# Why does the second spinner doesn't have margins/paddings

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

These are my `string arrays` that work just fine:

```
<string-array name="spinner1">
        <item>KB</item>
        <item>MB</item>
        <item>GB</item>
        <item>TB</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="spinner2">
        <item>Kb/s</item>
        <item>Mb/s</item>
        <item>Gb/s</item>
        <item>Tb/s</item>
</string-array>
```

This is the XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

This is how they look: [spinner1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA6Gu.jpg) and [spinner2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbjtL.jpg)

So far I can't find anything similar happening to someone else in other posts, wonder if any of you ran into this problem at all.

Here's what's in my MainActivity.java's OnCreate():

```
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
LoadSpin(spinner, spinner2);
```

Then outside of the OnCreate I have the LoadSpin() method:

```
public void LoadSpin(Spinner spin, Spinner spin2) {

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.spinner1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.spinner2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Comment: How you are filling that spinners?? Share your java code..!!

Comment: You are passing different layout type in adapters. I guess.

Comment: @jankigadhiya my bad, i forgot to do that. But I found the solution whike doing it. Mistyped the adapter. Posted the solution myself below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaaand now I just found my mistake. Right as I was editing this question I realize that my adapter2 wasn't setting the setDropDownViewResource correctly because I mistyped "adapter" instead of "adapter2" while copy/pasting:

```
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

So I just needed to correct it by doing this:

```
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin2.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Damn copy/paste mistakes! lol. Took me days to find this out. Think I need a break...